# Granting USB Root Access to Fender Mustang Plug

Tags: usb, ubuntu-studio

I'm a total Linux noob (learning little by little), and I am trying to get my Mustang Plug app to recognize my Mustang III amp that's connected via USB. I've found documentation that suggests the following:

"Various distributions allow only root to access USB devices of unknown type. To change this and allow users in "plugdev" group to also have access to Mustang amp create file /etc/udev/rules.d/50-mustang.rules (or /lib/udev/rules.d/50-mustang.rules on systemd systems) containing lines:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0004", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0006", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0007", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0010", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0011", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0012", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0013", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0014", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0015", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0016", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0017", GROUP="plugdev"

Verify that the "plugdev" group exists in your system, OR remember to use a valid group containing your user.

Now either restart computer or unplug amp and restart udev subsystem with the following command:

~ $ sudo service udev restart

or on systemd:

~ $ sudo systemctl restart udev"

I apologize if this sounds completely ignorant, but how do I create the file mentioned above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo touch /etc/udev/rules.d/50-mustang.rules` will create an empty file with that name and then you can `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/50-mustang.rules` to edit the file in nano.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I am a step further. However, when I paste the text lines into the new file and attempt to save, I receive the following error message: "Failed to save terminal contents, Error opening file "/etc/udev/rules.d/50-mustang.rules": Permission denied...I have administrator privileges, so is there any reason for me to not be able to edit the file I've created?

Comment: Then create the file somewhere else then copy it using sudo to the needed location.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Thanks!